# ZF Error Handler not working

Tags: php, zend-framework, error-handling

I'm trying to set up custom error handling, so I setup an ErrorController.php file within the default module, under the controllers directory.  However, when I try to go to access an invalid controller, an error is shown that an uncaught exception occurred.  This bypasses the ErrorController file though, and when I print the contents of the response object, it does not show any exceptions.  Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong here?  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I fixed the issue, apparently all I needed to do was add the following code: $front->throwExceptions(false);

Comment: You can also configure this per environment in your configuration file, ie `resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0`

Comment: I actually had that set already, but it didn't work.  I'll check again to see if I can get it to work this way.

Comment: Make sure you use the correct ENV value set in htaccess or in vhost, if there's no value set for APPLICATION_ENV the production env will be used and there's no errors shown in view.